# Replace Door Threshold Saddle

Tags: doors, exterior

I have an issue with the threshold for the back door of my home.  I had to replace the door itself (long story short I needed to install a dog door and didn’t want to mess with the glass in the original door).  Everything went well with the replacement and it works great with the exception of a decent amount of resistance when opening/closing as the bottom of the door/weatherstrip makes contact with the adjustable threshold saddle.  The resistance is enough to put some strain on the bottom hinge.  I first tried to lower the saddle using the adjustment screws and found that they were pretty badly stripped and very difficult to adjust (dirt/debris, who knows).

So, in my mind I have three options:

- Remove/replace the adjustable saddle.  I cannot for the life of me see any way to remove this thing.  I also haven’t found anything that matches it exactly anywhere online so finding a suitable replacement might be tough/impossible, even if I manage to remove the old one.
- Hack into the adjustable saddle and somehow force it lower.  It’s made of plastic, so I could probably sand or cut away at the top.  This doesn't seem like an ideal option.
- Replace the entire threshold.  This seems like the cleanest option and the right way to go, but it also seems like a pretty big job.  It’s kind of an odd door configuration: there are two “doors” (only one of which is actually hinged and opens, the other is fixed in place) that have a jamb between them and the threshold goes underneath both doors in one piece.  Seems that I would have to remove both doors and the doorjamb in order to cleanly remove/replace the entire threshold.

I'm a fairly competent DIYer, there just seem to be some potential major headaches involved with this if I go about it the wrong way.  Thanks in advance for any insight.

[image: door exterior]

[image: threshold]

Comment: It may be very low profile, but is there a sweep on the bottom of the door? Is the original and new door panel the same height? If there is no sweep and the bottom of door is hitting the threshold, there is your problem

Comment: Looking closely at the first photo, it appears there is a rubber sweep,on the back of the door. If this is the case, then it sounds like the door itself is rubbing on the saddle. I would cut the plastic saddle out and install a full door sweep gasket that mounts under the door. Much like this: http://m.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-E-O-1-3-4-in-x-36-in-Universal-Drip-Cap-Door-Bottom-UDB36BR/100174107